# Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In my experience, `input type="text"` `onchange` event usually occurs only after you leave (`blur`) the control.

Is there a way to force browser to trigger `onchange` every time `textfield` content changes? If not, what is the most elegant way to track this “manually”?

Using `onkey*` events is not reliable, since you can right-click the field and choose Paste, and this will change the field without any keyboard input.

Is `setTimeout` the only way?.. Ugly :-)

Answer (score 306, accepted):

***Update:***

See [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text/26202266#26202266) (2015).

---

*Original 2009 Answer:*

So, you want the `onchange` event to fire on keydown, blur, *and* paste? That's magic.

If you want to track changes as they type, use `"onkeydown"`. If you need to trap paste operations with the mouse, use `"onpaste"` ([IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536955(VS.85,loband).aspx), [FF3](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.onpaste)) and `"oninput"` ([FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhxklln.php)<sup>1</sup>).

<sup>1</sup><sub>Broken for `<textarea>` on Safari. Use [`textInput`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhiwalm.php) instead</sub>

Comment: Haven’t you checked oninput in IE (Don’t have it on a Mac)? Because checking for paste itself is not enough: you can select and cut, for example. Thanks.

Comment: `onkeypress` should be used instead of `onkeydown`. `onkeydown` fires when a key is clicked down. If a user holds down a key, the event will only fire once for the first character. `onkeypress` fires whenever a char is added to the text field.

Comment: It's not quite magic to make `onchange` fire on all those actions.  `<input onchange="doSomething();" onkeypress="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">` will do well enough for most.

Comment: What about deleting some text in input box using mouse? I don't think this will work.

Comment: I agree with @DeaDEnD. In fact, I think the trio of events `input` + `onpropertychange` + `onkeypress` is better than `input` + `onpaste` + `onkeydown`. `onpropertychange` is IE's counterpart to `input`.

Comment: With jquery 1.8.3, looks like: `$().on('change keydown paste input', function() {})`

Comment: if using `onkeydown` it may be a good idea to check for `.isChar` and filter out `.key` values like `'Shift'`, `'Control'`, etc...

Comment: It might be worth noting that, according to the spec, onpaste is cancelable, whereas oninput is not.

Comment: Refer to @Robert-Siemer's answer below. It should be the new accepted answer.

Comment: @MaxPMagee: yaar it should. Stack is such a wasteland of outdated information these days. I've updated this answer to reference [@RobertSiemer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/45433). I don't have time to police my 7 year old answers so thank you for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: This answer is DEPRECATED... look the Robert Siemer answer is the modern one and far better

Comment: @AriWais: YES, omg most of SO should be deprecated. Folks this answer is *8 years old*. I wish there was a "deprecate" button for old answers such as this one, and the community could choose the better one.

Comment: Hm, what about cut and undo events?

Answer (score 942):

**These days listen for [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput).**  It feels like [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) without the need to lose focus on the element. It is HTML5.

It’s supported by everyone (even mobile), except IE8 and below. For IE add `onpropertychange`. I use it like this:

```js
const source = document.getElementById('source');
const result = document.getElementById('result');

const inputHandler = function(e) {
  result.innerText = e.target.value;
}

source.addEventListener('input', inputHandler);
source.addEventListener('propertychange', inputHandler); // for IE8
// Firefox/Edge18-/IE9+ don’t fire on <select><option>
// source.addEventListener('change', inputHandler);
```

```html
<input id="source">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Support for `oninput` even in IE9 though is partial (https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event).

Answer (score 68):

Below code works fine for me with Jquery 1.8.3

HTML : `<input type="text" id="myId" />`

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$("#myId").on('change keydown paste input', function(){
      doSomething();
});
```

Comment: The jQuery **library** isn't tagged in the question.

Comment: Jquery is a Javascript api, and I was brought here by a search with Jquery keyword, I don't think it's worth creating a new question for each javascript qustion for the Jquery answer...

Comment: If people weren't allowed to suggest the use of libraries in answers there would be A LOT more unanswered questions on SO

Comment: Fires multiple times. Likely due to change and keydown. Likely input is only needed here.

Comment: you don't need the `keydown` because it will duplicate the value of the input, remove it.

Answer (score 49):

Javascript is unpredictable and funny here.

- `onchange` occurs only when you blur the textbox
- `onkeyup` & `onkeypress` doesn't always occur on text change
- `onkeydown` occurs on text change (but cannot track cut & paste with mouse click)
- `onpaste` & `oncut` occurs with keypress and even with the mouse right click.

So, to track the change in textbox, we need `onkeydown`, `oncut` and `onpaste`. In the callback of these event, if you check the value of the textbox then you don't get the updated value as the value is changed after the callback. So a solution for this is to set a timeout function with a timeout of 50 mili-seconds (or may be less)  to track the change.

This is a dirty hack but this is the only way, as I researched.

Here is an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/2BfGC/12/

Comment: `oninput` and `textInput` are the events which is the actual solution for this but, its not supported by all the browsers.

Comment: For the second bullet point I assume you meant `onkeyup` and `onkeydown`, which are similar. Both can capture Ctrl, Alt, Shift, and Meta keys. For the third bullet point I assume you meant `onkeypress`.

Answer (score 26):

I think in 2018 it's better to use the `input` event.

-

As the WHATWG Spec describes (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input):

> Fired at controls when the user changes the value (see also
>   the [change event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-change))

-

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<input type="text" oninput="handleValueChange()">
```

Comment: This sounds right. Lots of developers seem to forget IMEs an voice dictation and swiping exist. Non game input, asking for a specific keycode is accessibility hostile and probe to breaking. Rule of thumb is, read text when focus is lost... Not before. If you want to be an IME, see what Octo.app did.

Answer (score 16):

`onkeyup` happens after you type for example I press `t` when I lift the finger the action happens but on `keydown` the action happens before I digit the character `t`

Hope this is helpful for someone.

So `onkeyup` is better for when you want to send what you just typed now.

Answer (score 11):

Use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title here</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input oninput="onclickhandler(this)"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function onclickhandler(e) {
  console.log(e.value);
}
```

Comment: nice example, but really that handler should have a more appropriate name !

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar requirement (twitter style text field). Used `onkeyup` and `onchange`. `onchange` actually takes care of mouse paste operations during lost focus from the field.

*[Update]* In HTML5 or later, use `oninput` to get real time character modification updates, as explained in other answers above.

Comment: The oninput is useful if you want to detect when the contents of a textarea, input:text, input:password or input:search element have changed, because the onchange event on these elements fires when the element loses focus, not immediately after the modification.

Comment: @hkasera Yes, with HTML5 `oninput` is the way to go. But, when I implemented, HTML5 didn't exist and we had IE 8 :( . I appreciate your update as it provides up-to-date information for users.

Answer (score 8):

Please, judge next approach using JQuery:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" />
```

Javascript(JQuery):

```
$("#inputId").keyup(function() {
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).focus();
});

$("#inputId").change(function() {
    // Do whatever you need to do on actual change of the value of the input field
});
```

Comment: I use the same way : )

Comment: I realize this isn't the newest answer, but wouldn't blurring and re-focusing the input on every keyup screw up the cursor placement if it was anywhere except the end of the input?

Comment: @MichaelMartin-Smucker You'd think so, but apparently not: https://jsfiddle.net/gsss8c6L/

Comment: This brings an unexpected keyboard behavior in Android when used inside a webview. If the keyboard is opened for an input element and I either turned on all caps or switched to number view, as soon as I type a single character, all caps/number row is reset and a normal lowercase keyboard is shown - it is behaving like if I dismiss they keyboard and open it again for each character input.

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:** Add an event listener for `input`:

```
element.addEventListener("input", myFunction);
```

**Method 2:** Define the `oninput` property with JavaScript:

```
element.oninput = function()
{
    myFunction();
};
```

**Method 3:** Define the `oninput` property with HTML:

```
<input type="text" oninput="myFunction();">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use ONLY Internet Explorer, you can use this:

```
<input type="text" id="myID" onpropertychange="TextChange(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function TextChange(tBox) {
        if(event.propertyName=='value') {
            //your code here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could be for an in-house project I guess... :)

Comment: for me this helps, I'm developping a project for some mobile with an embedded OS where IE is the only browser.

Comment: I use ONLY Internet Explorer and I have finally found my answer!

Comment: 2021 and I wish I lived at that time

Comment: @AkshayKNair You don't. Most of us are still in therapy

Answer (score 4):

there is a quite near solution (do not fix all Paste ways) but most of them:

It works for inputs as well as for textareas:

```
<input type="text" ... >
<textarea ... >...</textarea>
```

Do like this:

```
<input type="text" ... onkeyup="JavaScript: ControlChanges()" onmouseup="JavaScript: ControlChanges()" >
<textarea ... onkeyup="JavaScript: ControlChanges()" onmouseup="JavaScript: ControlChanges()" >...</textarea>
```

As i said, not all ways to Paste fire an event on all browsers... worst some do not fire any event at all, but Timers are horrible to be used for such.

But most of Paste ways are done with keyboard and/or mouse, so normally an onkeyup or onmouseup are fired after a paste, also onkeyup is fired when typing on keyboard.

Ensure yor check code does not take much time... otherwise user get a poor impresion.

Yes, the trick is to fire on key and on mouse... but beware both can be fired, so take in mind such!!!

Answer (score 4):

"input" worked for me.

```
var searchBar  = document.getElementById("searchBar");
searchBar.addEventListener("input", PredictSearch, false);
```

Answer (score 4):

To track each try this example and before that completely reduce cursor blink rate to zero.

```html
<body>
//try onkeydown,onkeyup,onkeypress
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction(this.value)">
<span> </span>
<script>
function myFunction(val) {
//alert(val);
var mySpan = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;
mySpan += val+"<br>";
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = mySpan;
}
</script>

</body>
```

onblur : event generates on exit

onchange : event generates on exit if any changes made in inputtext

onkeydown: event generates on any key press (for key holding long times also)

onkeyup  : event generates on any key release

onkeypress: same as onkeydown (or onkeyup) but won't react for ctrl,backsace,alt other

Answer (score 4):

2018 here, this is what I do:

```
$(inputs).on('change keydown paste input propertychange click keyup blur',handler);
```

If you can point out flaws in this approach, I would be grateful.

Comment: 2019 here, and this will fire multiple times for each keypress. For an example, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/sp00n82/3r4691tq/5/

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress` events as well.