# Constant function run when user typing into input tag

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how I would have the TextEdit function run every time the text is removed. Currently, it is only updating when I unfocus the input tag.

```js
function textEdit(e) {
  document.getElementById("outputTxtBtn").innerHTML = e.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="title" id="inputTxtBtn" value="About me" onblur="textEdit(this)" />

<a title="About me" id="outputTxtBtn" href="#">About Me</a>
```

Comment: @John Use `oninput`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html text input onchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169353/html-text-input-onchange-event)

Comment: @Tyler while the answers are the same, the questions seem to be relatively distinct

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @dGRAMOP The OP here wants an real onchange event. Which is what the OP in the other question wanted too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `oninput` to listen for any type of *value modification*

```js
function textEdit(e) {
  document.getElementById("outputTxtBtn").innerHTML = e.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="title" id="inputTxtBtn" value="About me" oninput="textEdit(this)" />

<a title="About me" id="outputTxtBtn" href="#">About Me</a>
```

To prevent unwanted scripts injection use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.
To keep your JS well contained and easy debuggable - remove inline JS from your HTML markup

```js
function textEdit() {
  document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-textedit")).textContent = this.value;
}

[...document.querySelectorAll("[data-textedit]")].forEach(el => 
  el.addEventListener("input", textEdit)
);
```

```html
<input data-textedit="#outputTxtBtn" type="text" name="title" value="About me">
<a id="outputTxtBtn" href="#!">About me</a><br>

<input data-textedit="#test" type="text" name="title" value="Lorem">
<p id="test" href="#!">Lorem</p>
```