# Getting the length of a textbox value or content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is something that's driving me nuts:

I have this code and it works: I am trying to learn JavaScript before becoming addicted to JQuery. My sample project involves getting the value of the text-box, and validating according to it's length. the name of the form is ***membership***.

***Example: This works:***

```
function validateForm()
{
    var element = document.membership;

    if(element.txtName.value == "")
    {
        element.txtName.className = "alert";
    }
    else
    {
        element.txtName.className = "";
    }
}
```

***But this doesn't:***

```
function validateForm()
{
    var element = document.membership;
    var nameLenght = element.txtName.value.lenght;

    if(nameLenght < 1)
    {
        element.txtName.className = "alert";
    }
    else
    {
        element.txtName.className = "";
    }
}
```

Just an FYI: I am new to JavaScript but very familiar with the syntax. I just want to learn the basics and move up.

I even read some solutions on here but feel I am simply sinking deeper.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you really mean lenght or length?

Comment: Are you able to retrieve your element by using document.membership;? I would suggest using document.getElementById() or getElementsByClassName ()

Comment: Sorry about the type: I meant: length. My bad. It's called being too used to intellisense. I am using NotePad.

Comment: Thanks my friends. I am so use to writing C# in visual studio and strong type languages. I have to be very careful because I misspelled but never got an error. even when I pasted the code in Dreamweaver CS6. By the way: The reason I am using var element = document.membership; is because I do not want to call each element by ID individually, is this a bad thing?

Comment: So the problem really was the typo? Then you should revert the edit.

Comment: @Filix Kling: I did, thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be it is just because of typo in [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) here:

```
element.txtName.value.lenght;
```

must be `element.txtName.value.length;`. 
If you want it to run every time user presses key , then look here: [How to check string length with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046797/how-to-check-string-length-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function as well

```
var a = txtName.value;
            if (a.length < 1) {
                alert('your message');
                return false;
            }
```