# Input event triggered on Internet Explorer when placeholder changed

Tags: javascript, html

As it is shown in this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wWbE7/5/) when i change placeholder it triggers input event. I tested it on I.E 11 version but i guess that older versions have same problem. The other browsers does not behave like this. Is this I.E bug ? If so what is workaround for this problem on I.E ?

Here is html markup.

```
<input type="text" />
<button>Change PlaceHolder</button>
```

And here is javascript part.

```
var i = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
  $('input').attr('placeholder','placeholder ' + i++);
});

$('input').bind('input',function(){
    alert('input even occur');
});
```

Comment: please read about input event at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: if this issue is on earlier versions of IE you may use placeholder.js

Comment: I have the same problem, changing placeholder does indeed trigger input event. in IE 10 and 11, previous IE do not support placeholder natively so don't have the problem.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289396/jquery-input-event-fired-on-placeholder-in-ie

Comment: It is an IE 10/11 bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810538/ie-11-fires-input-event-on-focus

Answer (score 3):

checking if input is focused should be enough

```
$('input').bind('input',function(){
    if($(document.activeElement) != $('input'))
        return;
    alert('input even occur');
});
```

this also "fixes" the input event being triggered without any actions when placeholder contains an accented character

Comment: hmm that does fix it only partially. When you click on the textbox, it clears the placeholder, which triggers the input event - and the control is focused.

Comment: indeed, but that's another problem

Comment: Similar problem occurs (always with IE 11) when the input value acontains "acute" character. Example <input type="text" id="myInput" value="léon" oninput="myFunction()">