# how to get runtime value of one text box and show it to other text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having two text boxes namely Amount 1 and Amount 2 as like below..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRhLg/)

```
<input name="name1" id="id1" value="" type="radio" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount 1&nbsp;$ <input name="amtname" size="5" maxlength="7" value="" ><br><br>
<input name="name1" id="id2" value="" type="radio" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Amount 2&nbsp;$ <input name="amtname" size="5" maxlength="7" value="" ><br>
```

If I type any value in Amount 1 text box, it should display the same value in Amount 2 text box by getting runtime value from Amount 1 Text box.
And If I click on Amount 1 Checkbox, it should display the value of Amount 1 Text box in Amount 2 Text Box.
Is it possible using javascript?

Comment: use `onkeypress` or `onkeyup` event and assign value to second text box

Comment: where are you using `html5` here ?

Comment: Thanks....talking from the future =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a **`onkeyup`** event listener to your first element(Whenever a key is pressed, the value in first textbox is also entered in second.).  Then call the function like

```
function enterAmt(ev) {
    document.getElementById('amt2').value = ev.value;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRhLg/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the input's to an event such as onKeyPress or similar and change the other input's value to the changed one's.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/574971/2110909

[Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/on-input-change-event/6458949#6458949)

Example:

```
function updateBoth() {
    document.getElementsByName("amtname")[0].value = this.value;
    document.getElementsByName("amtname")[1].value = this.value
}

document.getElementsByName("amtname")[0].oninput = updateBoth;
document.getElementsByName("amtname")[1].oninput = updateBoth;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZRhLg/1/

Note: `oninput` may not be entirely cross-browser supported

Comment: Have a look at that, updated. I read your question again, I may have got it a bit twisted. If so, just tell me what needs to be changed...

Answer (score 0):

Save value in a variable and assign it to other textbox. Assign IDs to your textboxs assuming their ids are id1, id2 respectively. Now in event firing code use this.

```
var firstvalue = document.getElementById("id1").value;
document.getElementByID("id2").value = firstvalue;
```

Comment: reason for down voting ?