# count number of multiple selected in jquery autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, autocomplete

In jquery's **autocomplete multiple value**, I try to add a counter for selected values. It also should get updated immediately, when I chose/add one more values.

Both codes of a workaround are not working.

1

```
function checkReceiver()
{
var str = document.forms[0].tags.value,
regex = /417/igm,
count = str.match(regex),
count = (count) ? count.length : 0;
console.log(count);
document.forms[0].receiver.value=count;
}
```

2

```
var str = document.forms[0].tags.value;
count = (str.match(/417/g) || []).length;
document.forms[0].receiver.value=count;
```

Is there an trigger, I can use in the autocomplete function directly?

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doschni/mkLxt8xs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close to the working solution. I propose the following changes:

**Instead of testing for regex, simply split on commas**: The plugin you are using puts a comma automatically after each new selected value. Therefore, you can simply count the number of values by the number of commas. As an example:

```
function checkReceiver() {
    var str = document.forms[0].tags.value; 
    var words = str.split(',');                   // split on commas
    var count = words.length - 1;                 // a correction for the first element
    document.forms[0].receiver.value = count;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also split on spaces:`var words = str.split(' ');`, if you think that users might delete the last comma. Splitting on spaces assumes at least a space between two values.

**Make sure that the function is called on any change**: To make sure that the `checkReceiver()` function is called at any possible change, you need to make sure that it captures all events. One way of capturing the events in the `<input>` element is by forcing a check upon any possible change. As an example (method from the comments [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text/574971#574971)):

```
    <input type="text" name="numbers" id="tags" class="input_text clearable" size="50"
    onchange="checkReceiver();" 
    onkeypress="this.onchange();" 
    onpaste="this.onchange();" 
    oninput="this.onchange();" 
    placeholder="Choose Receiver" tabindex="1" value="" autofocus>
```

Additionally, you also want to call `checkReceiver()` when the autocomplete list *closes*. Therefore:

```
    .autocomplete({
       close: function(event, ui) {
          checkReceiver();                        // call checkReceiver() upon close
       }, ...
```

With these changes in place, the program works as expected. See **[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuhnrqwq/)**.

I can also recommend you to take a look at [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) which is specifically designed for multiple-input autocomplete text entries, and works in a very intuitive manner. For example, with Tokeninput you can use the **onAdd** and **onDelete** Callbacks ([see here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html#onadd-ondelete)). With these callbacks, you can then simply increase (*onAdd*) and decrease (*onDelete*) a counter variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean-Paul, for your great working solution! Also for your well documented answer - wow!! With token, I have no experience yet, but on a future project I will try (I also like them here on stackoverflow, when adding tags to open the question). On my actual autocomplete selectbox hang more functions - to change would cost too much time.

Comment: @doschni: Nice to hear that you like the answer! I expected it to take too much time to change everything, but it's always nice to learn about new plugins; especially for future projects :)