# disallow special characters in input fields

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate the passcode input field exclude special characters.
Basically i just want to allow letters or
 numbers
for some reason is not detecting characters like `, ´. ç, etc.

```
$('#passcode').on('keypress', function(e) {
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (!/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gb5kc12z/

Try with % or ´, ç, `

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Of course, I had to make some assumptions about the HTML you are using. You didn't provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: I'm curious: are you storing that passcode in plaintext? Because there is literally no other reason to limit a password-like input, and this reason isn't a good one either because you should be hashing your passwords with bcrypt, argon or PBKDF2, in which case it makes no difference what values are in your password.

Comment: can't reproduce your bug, it work fine for me; +1 @Nzall

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're testing by pasting in those special characters instead of typing them?  Your code only tests when a user releases a key to type in a character.  See [Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text) for more detail on how to track all value change events on an input field in modern browsers.