# Angular, typescript change detection input text

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange, watch

I can't find simple and easy solution how to detect change in my textfield.
I dont want to use `(keypress)` because the user will sometimes paste values into the field. (onchange) for example is working only when user will blur field. And I want to detect change immediately.

What is the easiest angular js $watch equivalent?

Comment: You can subscribe to the `oninput` event. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/556449

Comment: Thx, good to know this low-level html event.
I will use angular ngModelChange event in my case.

Comment: While this question is marked as being duplicate, I disagree. The linked question is about pure javascript, while this question is more on angular's way of doing things.

Answer (score 25):

use `ngModelChange`

```
input id="form_name" [(ngModel)]="quantity" (ngModelChange)="calculateTotal($event)"
```

Comment: Thx, looks pretty nice

Comment: The calculateTotal($event) method event is executed before the [(ngModel)]="quantity" is updated.

Comment: @Zindokar It is because you put (ngModelChange) before [(ngModel)]. The first one written will be the first one triggered.