# not hiding dropdown when focus changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's imagine I have three inputs :

```
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<input type="text" id="c">
```

and one `div` table that should drop down when writing some data into `input "a"` or `input "b"`. 
Well the logic I want to to take is:{
if you click and add some data to `input a` show that table to me->table appears->if I click on `input b` dont hide that `div`, however if I click somewhere else for example in `input c`, hide the table.
It's been 3rd day I cannot do this.
P.S. My boss told not to use $timeout. It should be done with blur and focus

Comment: please provide  full code

Comment: that code is understandable only by me, I just want to know how to perform this.

Comment: Try it by yourself first

Comment: Use the keydown and keyup events and hide/show your table elements when they are triggered. Also have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text

Comment: @Dr.Abbos If that code is understandable to only you then its of no use to us.

Comment: I tried, it works with $timeout, and it works not really properly for example if I click on input a -> table appears -> I click on input b table still appears(that actually I wanted to do) but when I click on input b first and then change to a input table disappears

Comment: Going by your use of $timeout you are using angular. Why is this not tagged in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap input `a` and `b` in same class and then use `blur` and `focus` on that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showab').hide();
$("input.change").focus(function(){
    $('#showab').show();
}); 
$("input.change").blur(function(){
    $('#showab').hide();
});
});
```

```css
input{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="change" type="text" id="a">
<input class="change" type="text" id="b">
<input type="text" id="c">
<div id="showab">table here</div>
```

Comment: thanks @ab29007 I will try to implement the logic to my code, and share the answer in minutes

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#showData").hide();

function lookup(arg) {
    var id = arg.getAttribute('id');
    var value = this.value;
    console.log(id);
    if (id === "a" || id === "b") {
        $("#showData").show();

    } else {
        $("#showData").hide();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="lookup(this);" onClick="lookup(this);">
<input type="text" id="b" onkeyup="lookup(this);" onClick="lookup(this);">
<input type="text" id="c" onkeyup="lookup(this);" onClick="lookup(this);">
<div id="showData">A Or B is Clicked here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make use of classes when hiding or showing your div containing the table.

Also take note of the Jquery `focus` (click into) and `blur` (click out of) classes

```js
$(".show").focus(function()
{
   $('#showTable').show();
});
  
$(".show").blur(function()
{
  $('#showTable').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="show" type="text" id="a">
<input class="show" type="text" id="b">
<input class="dontShow" type="text" id="c">
<div id="showTable" hidden="hidden">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>test 1</th><th>test 2</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```