# Html pattern matching event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to call some javascript function instantly once the pattern is matched in input field? Is there any specific event for that?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-z|A-Z]{2}$" (keyup.enter)="checkSth()">
```

I would like to call this `checkSth()` immediately without clicking enter when the pattern is matched.

Comment: Use a keyup? Without the enter, just keyup.

Comment: `onkeyup` or `onkeydown`

Comment: you have to use `oninput`event [as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/2803565)  to track changes, then check that pattern and call your checkSth() function if required.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an event listener in your javascript like such

**html**

```
<input id="input" />
```

**js**

```
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('keyup', () => console.log('changed'))
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ew8ywk7y/

Comment: That fires whenever the field is changed. The question was asking how to run it when the pattern is matched.

Comment: What would be the difference between this and what he's already doing with the `keyup` attribute? Furthermore, it's impossible to do what he's trying to accomplish, he can validate the regexp inside the event listener.

Comment: @Baruch you should type atSignUsername (@+Quentin) to inform he from your comment!