# Creates a map from multiple strings. Whenever the input string changes, the map will change accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to create a map from multiple strings. And whenever the input string changes, the map changes accordingly.

I'm having a simple issue I can't seem to fix. Below is a simplified version:

HTML:

```
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-1">
    <input type="text" id="filter_tags" name="filter_tags" value="tags11,tags12">
</div>
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-2">
    <input type="text" id="filter_tags" name="filter_tags" value="tags21,tags22">
</div>
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-3">
    <input type="text" id="filter_tags" name="filter_tags" value="tags31,tags32">
</div>
```

JS Idea:
Part1: Merge all the *#filter_tags* value into *window.hint_arr* value

```
var $ = jQuery;
window.hint_arr = function(){
    var array_filter_tags       = [];
    var count                   = 1;
    $(".boo-card-link").each(function(){
        var id                  = count;
        var tmp_filter_tags     = $("#txtfilter_tags").val();
        tmp_filter_tags         = tmp_filter_tags.replace(/\s/g, '');
        var json_filter_tags    = tmp_filter_tags.split(',');
        count++;
        array_filter_tags       = $.merge(array_filter_tags, json_filter_tags).unique();
    });
    array_filter_tags = array_filter_tags.join();
    return array_filter_tags;
};
window.hint_arr(); //result: tags11,tags12,tags21,tags22,tags31,tags32
```

Part2: Convert string value to a map

```
var Convert = function() {
    var json = [];
    var to = ""+window.hint_arr();
    var toSplit = to.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < toSplit.length; i++) {
        json.push({"num":toSplit[i]});
    }
    a = function() {
        console.log(json);
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            a()
        }
    }
}();
Convert.init(); //result: [{num:'tags11'},{num:'tags12'},{num:'tags21'},{num:'tags22'}...]
```

Until this step, everything is fine. The problem I encountered is that when changing the value of any input, a map called "json" does not change accordingly.

```
$('#filter_tags').on('change', function() {
    console.log(window.hint_arr());
});
$('#filter_tags').trigger('change');
```

For example when the first input changes the value from *value = "tags11, tags12"* to *value = "tags11, tags12, tags13"*, the result of window.hint_arr () has changed to *'tags11,tags12,tags13,tags21,tags22,tags31,tags32'* but the map *json* constant. I've tried to recall the Convert() Function but nothing seems to return what I'm looking for

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?.

Comment: Why are you using `$('#txtfilter_tags').on` when you have **filter_tags** as id. Another thing, don't repeat ids like classes, use a changed id for every element.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry for my typo mistake. Because I use 1 element input id and clone it each time I add other elements with different values. Then merge all the values back into the array. This does not cause the problem that I encountered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you can simplify your logic by a lot by just using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [(jQuery) .map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

The `onchange` event occurs when the value of an element has been changed [but after you leave the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text).

```js
// taken from another post
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)
    if (a.indexOf(this[i]) === -1)
      a.push(this[i]);
  return a;
}

// note 1: json is defined globally

var json = [];

$(function() {

  var inputs = $('input[name=filter_tags]').on('change', function() {
    // get all values e.g. 'tags11,tags12,tags21,tags22,tags31,tags11'

    // note 2: .get() is to convert jQuery array to normal array
    // note 3: .join() is to join all the values in the normal array

    var values = inputs.map(function() {
      return this.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    }).get().join(',');

    // console.log(values);

    // split all values and remove dups e.g. ['tags11','tags12','tags21','tags22','tags31']

    var tags = values.split(',').unique();

    // console.log(tags);

    // convert tags e.g. [{ num: 'tags11' }, { num: 'tags12' }, ...]

    // note 4: this is not jQuery .map(), but Array.map()


    json = tags.map(function(tag) {
      return {
        'num': tag
      };
    });

    console.log(json);

  });

  // trigger change
  inputs.eq(0).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-1">
  <input type="text" name="filter_tags" value="tags11 ,tags12  ">
</div>
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-2">
  <input type="text" name="filter_tags" value="tags21,tags22">
</div>
<div class="boo-card-link" data-href="card-3">
  <input type="text" name="filter_tags" value="  tags31, tags11">
</div>
```

Array.unique() is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21445415/1022914).