# How do I use a text box as a constant input?

Tags: javascript, html, events, text, input

I am a beginner coder and I am having trouble with a simple program that basically says whatever you type into a text box under/above it. For example, if you type "Hello World" into the box, it will say "Hello World" in a paragraph under/above it. My current (faulty) code is this:

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<input id="ipone type="text">
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("ipone").value;
x = test;
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= document.getElementById("ipone").value;
</script>
```

I am trying to get it to work, and I am trying to have it as simple and small as possible. Please help.

Comment: The reason why this doesn't work is because the script is being called immediately. You don't actually get a chance to type something in and change the text so it just takes the blank input and doesn't run again. What the answer does is call a function when the input changes so the javascript doesn't run until the text has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you need is [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput), which triggers on any text typing, pasting, cutting, etc. by the user.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("ipone");
var paragraph = document.getElementById("test");

input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var value = input.value;
  paragraph.innerText = value;
});
```

```css
/* just for demonstration */
#test{
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<input id="ipone" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped your code into a function, and called that function whenever the input changes

more on the topic: [Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text)

```html
<p id="test"></p>
<input id="ipone" type="text" onchange="update()" onkeypress="update()" />
<script>
function update() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("ipone").value;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i've got it but who knows if i could word it better :0

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" id="txtDemo" onchange="myFunction()"/>
<p>Entered Text:<span id="value"></span> </p>
<script>
 function myFunction(){
  var inputValue=document.getElementById("txtDemo").value; 
  var p=document.getElementById("value")
  p.innerHTML=inputValue;
 }
</script>
```

This code may help you