# In real time type styled text onto screen as user types in textbox, using modern HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write a stylised font preview on the screen as a user types into a text box - like this (though I think this uses dated coding techniques):
https://www.pet-tags.co.uk/engravingdetail?product=57&size=2

I can't find a specific example doing this - I found this question which is similar but doesn't write out the output to the screen:
[Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text/26202266#26202266)

I'd like to ensure this is done in a modern way with wide contemporary browser support (so excluding, say, IE8 is fine).

I can find no specific examples of this online.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `onInput` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Any chance of a working example - also in that link above they say you should use oninput?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`onInput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event. I has quite a wide support: https://caniuse.com/#search=oninput.

Working example below:

```js
const $source = document.querySelector('#source');
const $result = document.querySelector('#result');

$source.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    $result.innerHTML = e.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input id="source" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I can't get this working. I've copied the above to an html file, wrapped the javascript in <script> tags added <html> and <body> & referenced jquery 3.3.1. A complete listing would be helpful - thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it in a code snippet?
I assume, you trying to access tags before they have rendered. Consider using `$(function () {
})` wrapper for entire js code

Comment: It's not clear how this code snippet works - or how to make it work in an actual page

Comment: @niico Use the wrapper or move `script` tag to the end of the `body` and it should work.

Comment: sorry which wrapper? You want me to put <div and <input in script tags?!?!

Comment: What is a 'code snippet'? I thought it was just the way of running code embedded on this site? How does this help me? (sorry I don't ask front end questions much)

Comment: @niico Consider using `$(function () { })` wrapper for entire js code

Comment: @niico html file example: `<html>
<body>
<input id="source" />

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
const $source = document.querySelector('#source');
const $result = document.querySelector('#result');

$source.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    $result.innerHTML = e.target.value;
})
</script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: That's exactly what I tried - except my div and input were *below* the script - so I guess the script needs to be below those?!

Comment: @niico that's one of the approaches. The other one is `window.onLoad` or `$(function () {/* your code here */})` which I was trying to describe to you earlier. But this is a basics of front-end programming, which you lack. You should start to learn the basics.