# Restrict user to type numbers or alphabets in input type

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular9

Is there any way to restrict the user from typing the wrong sequence, I mean that user is allowed to type first two character as alphabets only, then the next two as number and the next two as character and then the rest 4 as number. Basically I want to apply restriction on the sequence of the character. The format of the **Indian vehicle registration number** should not be altered with wrong entries.
sample output should be

> **HR 23 DU 2323**

```js
vehicleNumberFormat() {
    const { value } = this.myForm.get('vehicleNumber');
    console.log('value', value);

    const regex = /^(\w{0,2})(\w{0,2})(\w{0,2})(\w{0,4})$/g
    // const onlyNumbers = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
    const typedValue = value.replace(/[^\w]/g, '')

    const formatedVehicleNumber = typedValue.replace(regex, (regex, $1, $2, $3, $4) =>
      [$1, $2, $3, $4].filter(group => !!group).join(' ')
    )

    console.log('formatedVehicleNumber-->', formatedVehicleNumber.toUpperCase())
    this.myForm.controls['vehicleNumber']?.setValue(formatedVehicleNumber.toUpperCase());
    
    return formatedVehicleNumber;
  }
```

here the codebase [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-validator-vehicle-number-format2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Should be `/^([a-z]{2})(\d{2})([a-z]{2})(\d{2})$/gi` I believe

Comment: And I guess you want something related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/2398020 to handle typing into the form?

Comment: @MingweiSamuel it's not working, i have tried out. thanks for the response :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following regex should suffice your need

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+([a-zA-Z]{2})\s+(\d{4})$
```