# How to bind an event on input text contains data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

in the below posted html code, i have an  tag and i want to know how can i bind on the occurence of the event that indicates that the input text tag is fired. in other words.i want to fire or emit an event on the input
tag is filled with data, something like binding on (click) event in buttons
please let me know how to do that

**code**:

```
<span class="classOriginLat">
  <label for="originLatLabel">origin Latitude:</label>
  <input type="text" class="classInputOriginLat"id="originLatTextId" name="originLatText" required [(ngModel)]=IMeasurementCoordinates.originLat>
</span>
```

Comment: You may bind like this `<input (change)="onInputChange($event)"/>`. This expects `onInputChange(e)` method to be defined in controller.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML Template

```html
<input (change)="onInputChange($event)"/>
```

#### Controller method for the event

```js
onInputChange(e) {
 console.log('input change event data', e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

oninput can be your solution.

```js
var txtInputFilled = false;

function print(element) {
  if(element.value.length > 0) {
    console.log(element.value);
    txtInputFilled = true;
  }
  else {
    txtInputFilled = false;
  }
}

function check() {
  console.log("text input filled : " + txtInputFilled);
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" oninput="print(this);"/>
<button type="button" onclick="check();">check</button>
```

Take a look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574971/11851170) from similar question for various input cases.