# How do I clear an input search field with a 'x' button with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have this search which filters the elements directly when I type letters in the input field. And now I want to reset the search by clicking on the 'x'.

So far the filter only reacts 'live' and goes back to the initial state when I delete the letters with the backspace key. But when I click on the 'x' it just deletes my written letters. Other than that nothing happens and I have to press 'enter' in the input field to reset the search again.

But I would really love the search to reset itself (without having to press 'enter') when I click on the 'x' button.

That's my search in HTML. The span id="clear" is the 'x' button I'm talking about.

```
<div id="Search">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="nach AdSpecial suchen" id="adSearch" onkeyup="search_ads()">
    </div>
    <span id="clear" onclick="clearSearch()"></span>
</div>
```

And that's my JavaScript code. All my elements that I want to filter have the class '.filterDiv'.

```
const search = document.getElementById("Search");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".filterDiv");

function search_ads() {
  let input = document.getElementById('adSearch').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('filterDiv');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display="";                 
        }
    }
}

function clearSearch() {
  document.getElementById('adSearch').value="";
}
```

This is my first post here, so I apologise if I forgot to mention some important informations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your clear function just call the search function after clearing the input.

```
function clearSearch() {
  document.getElementById('adSearch').value="";
  search_ads();
}
```

This will search ads for the now empty input (so you basically reset them aswell)

May I also suggest a little improvement:

Instead of calling the search function on each `keyup-event` you could call it on each `oninput-event` (see this question for more information on this) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202266/19529102)

Comment: Wow... it can be so simple.  Thank you very much! And thanks for the tip – I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

For clearing, you can add this line:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv').forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block')
```

I would recommend looking into [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) as they are much cleaner to use than `document.getElementByID` and `document.getElementsByClassName`.

To generally improve your code:

```js
const search = document.querySelector('#adSearch'),
      items = document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv'),
      clear = document.querySelector('#clear');

search.onkeyup = e => {
  let query = search.value.toLowerCase();
  for(let item of items){
    item.style.display = item.innerHTML.includes(input) ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
}


clear.onclick = e => {
  search.value = '';
  items.forEach(el => el.style.display = 'block');
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your recommendation. Since I'm a newbie in JavaScript, your recommendation really helps me out! Thank you!