# Javascript addEventlistener for 'change' event is not working on input

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript addEventlistener for 'change' event is not working on input.

I have series of inputs in a form, selected them using querySelectorAll, added event listener to each input using forEach loop. The goal is to get the value inside the input on change, so I can run my validation functions. This works fine on events like 'keyup' but according to docs 'change' event should also produce same result. Which it doesn't in my case. Or is change event is just limited to select tag in html.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  });
});
```

Comment: Info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event   Some "change" events may only trigger when the corresponding element loses focus (unlike "key" events, that are obviously triggered with each key stroke, while the element still has focus)

Comment: change event work with input after blur or focus out. try "input" event. i think its work

Comment: was just about to suggest the `input` event too

Comment: @QadeesJaved 'input' works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use 'input' event instead of 'change'